# What happens with Corretto now that OpenJDK 8 and 11 are no longer supported by Oracle?

Tags: java, corretto

Starting next week Oracle will no longer support free public releases for OpenJDK 8 or 11. 
They are also moving to a subscription model for all production use. 
How will this affect Corretto moving forward?

Comment: Corretto uses OpenJDK, which will still be usable without a subscription.

Comment: I have a vague feeling that your question is off-topic respectively in the "primary opinion based" bucket. This community is about programming questions, not about predicting the "future" of some 3rd party library or tool or service.

Answer (score 5):

There should be no impact on Corretto.  That's the idea, Oracle's action/inaction should have no impact if you use it.

From Amazon's Corretto FAQ here:

https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/faqs/#support

> Q: What is included in Corretto's long-term support?
>
> A: Long-term support (LTS) for Corretto includes performance enhancements and security updates for Corretto 8 until at least June 2023 at no cost. Updates are planned to be released quarterly. Amazon will provide LTS for Corretto 11 with quarterly updates until at least August 2024.

Comment: The oracle situaiton has been hyped up by media, causing developers to become confused without understanding what it actually is. :sadface: